# Join two tables and get from one table a array of values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: one, the **main** table displays the day of the week and the **soup** that day.
The table soups, has a list of possible soups.

```
+-----+------------+--------+
| id  | day        |id_soup |
+-----+------------+--------+
| 1   | Friday     | 1      |
| 2   | Saturday   | 1      |
| 3   | Sunday     | 2      |
+-----+------------+--------+

+-----+------------+
| id  | soup       | 
+-----+------------+
| 1   | potatoes   | 
| 2   | carrots    | 
| 3   | peas       |
+-----+------------+
```

To get the Friday soup (string not id) I can use a query like this:

```
SELECT ma.id, ma.day, ma.id_soup, so.soup
FROM main ma, soup so
WHERE ma.id_soup = so.id
AND ma.id = 1
```

I get something like this (OUTPUT)

```
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
| id  | day        | id_soup | soup     |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
| 1   | Friday     | 1       | potatoes |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
```

This works well if Friday is only available a single soup.

The problem is that on Friday will be available two soups (potatoes and peas -  an array of soups)

We need another table?

EDITED

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| id  | id_day  | id_soup |     
+-----+---------+---------+
| 1   | 1       | 1       |
| 2   | 1       | 2       |
| 3   | 2       | 2       |
| 4   | 2       | 3       |
| 5   | 3       | 1       |
| 6   | 3       | 3       |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

It is possible to obtain in a single query, in addition to other fields of the main table (id, day, id_soup), the soups array (potatoes, peas)?

What is the best way to construct this query?

EDITED:

Desired output (only to illustrate):

```
+-----+------------+---------+------------------+
| id  | day        | id_soup | soup             |
+-----+------------+---------+------------------+
| 1   | Friday     | 1       | potatoes, peas   |
+-----+------------+---------+------------------+
```

EDITED

Question: and if de desired output is like:

```
+-----+------------+-------------------+
| id  | day        | soup              |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| 1   | Friday     | potatoes, carrots |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| 2   | Saturday   | carrots, peas     |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| 3   | Sunday     | potatoes, peas    |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Whats your desired output...

Comment: You should try to match your data with the example provided. In this case friday should have potatoes and peas. Also please label your third table. And if you have that third table, then you dont need soup id on the `MAIN` tbale

Comment: Thanks Teja. I edited my fiddle.

Comment: why you need an array? and why id_soup doesnt have an array too?

Comment: Thanks Juan. This example is fictional. On the client side what is displayed is the day (Friday) and a list of soups that day (potatoes, peas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will need an intermediate table if there are multiple soups per day.
You can goup all the soups for a day using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `SELECT` statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT ma.id, ma.day, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT so.soup) as soup
FROM main ma
LEFT JOIN soupmain sm ON(ma.id = sm.id_main)
LEFT JOIN soup so ON(so.id = sm.id_soup)
WHERE ma.id = 1
GROUP BY ma.id
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll try in my query (this part is a detail) to see if I can make it work this way and I get the desired output. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my post. These solutions work well. Being to do a better study of this part of the SQL I have a doubt what is the best way to implement the clause GROUP_CONCAT but for get all the main table (Friday, Saturday and Sunday) soup. Any suggestion?

Comment: Then just do not put the `WHERE` and you will get all the days from the main table

Answer (score 2):

You can use a  group_concat

```
SELECT ma.day,  groupconcat(so.soup)
FROM main ma, soup so
WHERE ma.id_soup = so.id
AND ma.id = 1
group by ma.day
```